# Doc class Exam: how to control horizontal width of answer box / frame

Tags: formatting, multicol, multicolumn, exam

The MWE below specifies 2 column format - one problem per column. As presently coded, the step-by-step solution box is a bit narrow, causing hyphenation that negatively impacts readability (IMHO) and unnecessarily extends the length / depth of the solution box.

Since I didn't create this code, I'm confused about the parameters, specifically re: how to slightly increase the size of the solution box while still preserving the 2 column format, i.e. 1 problem at the top of each column.

You assistance is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II Review Ch 3.2: Operations Rational Expressions and Equations: K E Y}
       {}
       {01/13-14/21} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Obj. 3.2.a: I can simplify factored rational expressions and find their restrictions.
    \bigskip
    \bigskipSimplify expression and state the excluded values (+1 pt numerator, +1 pt denominator, +1 pt restrictions.) each equation. Show all work/steps on this page.}
  }}}
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
          }
% ------------ DOCUMENT STARTS HERE---------- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

%macro \diamondscheme. The lines are drawn too, you need not tikz. The size is controlled by the \diaw parameter. It is set to 1.5cm in this example.

% definition
\newdimen\diaw \diaw=1.5cm
\def\diamondscheme#1#2#3#4{%
    \vbox to\diaw{
       \kern-1ex
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#1$\hss}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hbox to0pt{\hss$#2$\hss}\hss
                     \raise.7ex\hbox{\diacross}\hss
                     \hbox to0pt{\hss$#3$\hss}}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#4$\hss}
       \kern-1ex
    }
}
\newcount\tmpnum 
\tmpnum=\diaw 
\divide\tmpnum by65781  % tmpnum is now equal to \diaw in bp units
\divide\tmpnum by2
\def\tmp{\the\tmpnum\space}
\edef\diacross{\pdfliteral
   {q 0.4 w -\tmp \tmp m \tmp -\tmp l S -\tmp -\tmp m \tmp \tmp l S Q}}

\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{10k^2+32k+24}{15k+18}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor 2 out of the numerator.\bigskip

$\dfrac{2(5k^2+16k+12)} {15k+18}$\bigskip

Now factor the numerator using diamond method. 
\bigskip
%call diamondscheme macro
\hspace{2cm}
\diamondscheme{60}{10}{6}{16}
\bigskip
The 5 in front of $5k^2$ means this is a non-monic quadratic trinomial. So use the box method to complete the factorization.

\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 
\hspace{1cm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | }
  \mcc{} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$5k$}} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$+6$}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$k$} & $5k^2$ & $6$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & $10k$ & $12$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.2cm}
Numerator factors to $\color{red}\dfrac{(5k+6)(k+2)}{\color{black} 15k+18}$ 

Now factor the bottom:

\hspace{2cm}$3(5k+6)$
\vspace{0.25cm}

Cancel common factors (this creates a HOLE in the graph):

\hspace{2cm}
$\dfrac{\cancel{(5k+6)}(k+2)}{3\cancel{(5k+6)}}$ 
\vspace{0.25cm}

Simplified form: $\dfrac{(k+2)}{3}$

\textcolor{blue}{\textbf {Reminder:}}

\textbf{Zeros occur on top} (in the numerator).

\textbf{VA's (vertical asymptotes) are restrictions in the denominator}...to prevent division by $0$.

\textcolor{red}
{Zeros: $k=-2$}

\textcolor{red}
{Holes: $k=-6/5$}

\textcolor{red}
{VA: $none$}

\end{solutionorbox}

\vspace{0.25cm}
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{5k^2+10k+24}{6k+12}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
step-by-step solution goes here
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I have well understood the problem!

May be you can modify the tasks environment options like this:

```
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
      after-skip=2cm,
      label-width=1.5em, % <---------
      item-indent=2em,  % <----------
      label=(\arabic*),
      column-sep=1em % <----------
      }
```

[image]

The figure is from the tasks package documentation

**The complete code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II Review Ch 3.2: Operations Rational Expressions and Equations: K E Y}
       {}
       {01/13-14/21} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Obj. 3.2.a: I can simplify factored rational expressions and find their restrictions.
    \bigskip
    \bigskipSimplify expression and state the excluded values (+1 pt numerator, +1 pt denominator, +1 pt restrictions.) each equation. Show all work/steps on this page.}
  }}}
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,  % <---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em   %  <----------
          }
% ------------ DOCUMENT STARTS HERE---------- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

%macro \diamondscheme. The lines are drawn too, you need not tikz. The size is controlled by the \diaw parameter. It is set to 1.5cm in this example.

% definition
\newdimen\diaw \diaw=1.5cm
\def\diamondscheme#1#2#3#4{%
    \vbox to\diaw{
       \kern-1ex
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#1$\hss}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hbox to0pt{\hss$#2$\hss}\hss
                     \raise.7ex\hbox{\diacross}\hss
                     \hbox to0pt{\hss$#3$\hss}}
       \vss
       \hbox to\diaw{\hss$#4$\hss}
       \kern-1ex
    }
}
\newcount\tmpnum 
\tmpnum=\diaw 
\divide\tmpnum by65781  % tmpnum is now equal to \diaw in bp units
\divide\tmpnum by2
\def\tmp{\the\tmpnum\space}
\edef\diacross{\pdfliteral
   {q 0.4 w -\tmp \tmp m \tmp -\tmp l S -\tmp -\tmp m \tmp \tmp l S Q}}

\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{10k^2+32k+24}{15k+18}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor 2 out of the numerator.\bigskip

$\dfrac{2(5k^2+16k+12)} {15k+18}$\bigskip

Now factor the numerator using diamond method. 
\bigskip
%call diamondscheme macro
\hspace{2cm}
\diamondscheme{60}{10}{6}{16}
\bigskip
The 5 in front of $5k^2$ means this is a non-monic quadratic trinomial. So use the box method to complete the factorization.

\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 
\hspace{1cm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | }
  \mcc{} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$5k$}} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$+6$}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$k$} & $5k^2$ & $6$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & $10k$ & $12$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.2cm}
Numerator factors to $\color{red}\dfrac{(5k+6)(k+2)}{\color{black} 15k+18}$ 

Now factor the bottom:

\hspace{2cm}$3(5k+6)$
\vspace{0.25cm}

Cancel common factors (this creates a HOLE in the graph):

\hspace{2cm}
$\dfrac{\cancel{(5k+6)}(k+2)}{3\cancel{(5k+6)}}$ 
\vspace{0.25cm}

Simplified form: $\dfrac{(k+2)}{3}$

\textcolor{blue}{\textbf {Reminder:}}

\textbf{Zeros occur on top} (in the numerator).

\textbf{VA's (vertical asymptotes) are restrictions in the denominator}...to prevent division by $0$.

\textcolor{red}
{Zeros: $k=-2$}

\textcolor{red}
{Holes: $k=-6/5$}

\textcolor{red}
{VA: $none$}

\end{solutionorbox}

\vspace{0.25cm}
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{5k^2+10k+24}{6k+12}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
step-by-step solution goes here
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @hafidBoukoulda. Thanks for the suggestions. New code shown below includes your suggested revisions. Renders correctly, but produces 2 similar errors _both "overfull \box". Error appears at this line:' \endtask'. Question: ignore errors or how to fix?'\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          %label-width=2em,
          label-width=1.5em,
         % item-indent=3em,
          item-indent=2em, 
          label=(\arabic*),
          %column-sep=2em
          column-sep=1em
          }'

Comment: Hi @WyoWindStorm. No errors for me in overleaf TeXlive 2019

Comment: PS How can I paste code as code in comments. I tried enclosing the code in 2 ~ and also two single quotes '.

Comment: @WyoWindStorm If needed you can reedit your question with the code updated

Comment: @WyoWindStorm answer updated with compilable code. I hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for so generously sharing your knowledge! BTW, in Overleaf, you have to comment out each  %<------------ for the code to compile. Can I safely ignore the 2 overfull \hbox errors which occur near end of document?